# Hide selected checkboxes in form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, checkbox, controls

I have a little problem about checkboxes. I want to hide the boxes that are selected when I press the button.

I wrote a piece of code like

```
foreach (CheckBox button in Controls)
        {
            if (button.Checked == true)
            {
                button.Hide();
            }
        }
```

It works but I get a logical error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What exact error did you get?

Comment: foreach (Control ctl in Controls)
        {
            if ( ctl is CheckBox) ctl.Visible = ((Checkbox)ctl).Checked;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the use of the Controls collection. This collection contains all the controls hosted by the form container. Trying to assign a control from this collection directly to a CheckBox results in a casting error.

Because not all controls in the form are checkboxes, you need to apply your logic only to checkbox controls.

It is easy with [OfType IEnumerable extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

```
foreach (CheckBox button in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    if (button.Checked)
        button.Hide();
}
```

This has also the advantage to allow the direct assignement to a variable of type CheckBox.